# Is it possible to access GetxController value from another GetxController? Flutter Get Package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I'm new in Flutter and so with GetX https://pub.dev/packages/get

Am I able to access value from "**another controller**" inside a **controller**?

Both of them will be initialized but I don't want to pass "**id**" at screens/widget/handlers etc., I want to do it between controller to controller only (if possible)

Here's an example

1. this is my first controller

   class firstController extends GetxController { var id = 1; }
2. this is my second controller and I want to access id from **firstController**

   class secondController extends GetxController {   var copiedIdFromFirstController = 1; }

I know this sounds silly but I love exploring things (lol)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you mean accessing one controller directly from another controller class, then yes you can.

```
class FirstController extends GetxController {
  int id = 1;
}

class SecondController extends GetxController {
  int idFromFirstController = Get.find<FirstController>().id;

  @override
    void onInit() {
      super.onInit();
      debugPrint('$idFromFirstController'); // prints 1
    }
}
```

The only thing you need to make sure is that the dependency is initialized first. So one way to make the above example work is to initialize both in main.

```
void main() {
  Get.put(FirstController()); // make sure this is first
  Get.put(SecondController());
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Hello there,  This is exactly what I want to do, Thank you!

Comment: Anything should I concern about this approach? Is it recommended or warned anywhere in the documentation?

Comment: I suppose that dives more into a general architecture question. But the GetX docs have examples of controllers depending on other controllers so I would't worry about it. Probably a good idea to have some core controllers that don't depending on anything else though, like database and API calls etc...

Comment: How would you listen to the first controller's ID variable so the second controller reacts to changes to the ID variable?

Comment: @fractal make `id` observable by adding `.obs` then subscribe to it using `ever` function. You can see an explanation of `ever` on this post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67134177/proper-way-to-persist-store-data-in-getxcontroller-in-flutter/67292928#67292928

Comment: @Loren.A could you provide a full example of this? Sadly I don't get it working..

Comment: @Jan that pretty much is a full working example. If you're having issues then post a separate question and paste the link here and I'll have a look.

Comment: @Loren.A thank you for your answer. I already found my problem!

Comment: Get.put(ControllerName(), permanent: true);

This will keep instance in memory so you can communicate between each controller

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do that like this:

```
class yourWidget extends StatelessWidget{
     FirstController fCTRL = Get.put(FirstController());
     SecondController sCTRL = Get.put(SecondController());
     //now you can have 
     print(fCTRL.id);  //1
     print(sCTRL.something);
}
```